# Angular Module federation with web components: how to share Ngrx store?

Tags: angular, ngrx, web-component, angular-module-federation

Months ago, I started a big project using module federation with web components as described in https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/aktuelles/multi-framework-and-version-micro-frontends-with-module-federation-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/
The shell must activate different remote modules developed in different angular versions, so this technique proved to be the great solution to make every team works without any interference.
Now I want to introduce Ngrx to share store and state between shell and remote modules, but I can't get It to work. I tried to share @ngrx/store but I got injection error in the remote module.

The only way I can get it work is to set in window object the reference to the store created by the shell:

`(window as any)['_MY_GLOBL_STORE'] = this.store;`

and referencing it in the remote by a provide factory:

```
    providers: [
      {
        provide: Store<AppState>, useFactory: () => {
          return (window as any)['_MY_GLOBL_STORE'];
        }
      }
    ]
```

It seems to work, but I don’t know if it is a good solution and if it may have some drawbacks/pitfalls.
Do you think is it correct and stable to share an angular object in window object? Any suggestions or an idea to solve the injection errors with MFE and web components?
Thanks

Comment: related? https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/issues/11